# adding <span> to PHP echo or styling

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to amend the custom layout from one of my WordPress plugins.

%1s and %2s below I would like to wrap in  to add a class so that I can add some styling to this elements but am unsure how to do this

```
<?php if (!is_quote()) : ?>
      <p><?php echo sprintf(__('We have sent you invoice %1s with a balance of %2s.', ud_get_wp_invoice()->domain), invoice_id(array('return' => true)), balance_due(array('return' => true))); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I have tried breaking up and adding span as so:

```
<?php echo sprintf(__('We have sent you invoice' <span>'%1s'</span> 'with a balance of' <span>'%2s'</span>'.', ud_get_wp_invoice()->domain)...
```

but no joy, I have never tried anything like this so am unsure what options I have

Comment: you forgot to escape single quotes inside the string. `'We have sent you invoice ' <span>'%1s'</span> 'with a balance of' <span>'%2s'</span>'` escape those with back slash `'We have sent you invoice \' <span>\'%1s\'</span> \'with a balance of\' <span>\'%2s\'</span>'`. I think that is the thing https://ideone.com/j2w3ph

Comment: @Alex sorted, thanks :-)